# Swift file - how to disable all warnings?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I want to disable all of the warnings (marked with yellow color) in the `Swift` file.
I've tried to add `-w` flag to `Build Phases`, but it doesn't work.
In `Objective-C` it works, but how to do that in `Swift`?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I'm curious. Why would you do that?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540446/how-to-silence-a-warning-in-swift-2-0

Comment: @QuentinHayot I have 3-rd party lib in my project.  After migration to Swift 2 - I have tons of warnings generated by it. I don't want to fix them, hope it's more clearer now )

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921884/in-xcode-how-to-suppress-all-warnings-in-specific-source-files

Comment: @Karthik, thanks, but it only works for ObjC projects.

Comment: There is no way to achieve that in Swift. Your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540446/how-to-silence-a-warning-in-swift-2-0.

Answer (score -1):

Target > Building Settings > Search "Warning" > Change Yes to No > Done

[image]

Comment: I want to disable warnings for concrete BlahBlahBlah.swift file, not in all project.

Comment: i don't know if that is possible.