# Is there any possible to Hide/Disable code warnings in swift project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

In IOS Objective C Projects i am using following way to Hide warnings. please check attached screenshot. But Swift based project its not working. Is there any possible to hide warnings?
[image: ObjectiveC Project]

Comment: Don't hide warnings, fix them.

Comment: Keep in mind that most warnings will lead to unexpected bugs or crashes. And getting into the habit of ignoring truly benign warnings will lead you to ignoring important warnings that really must be fixed. Personally, I turn on the setting to treat warnings as errors. I have a project will 250,000 lines of code (not a typo) and it compiles with 0 (none, nada, zilch, zero) warnings.

Comment: While I agree you should fix and not silence, your question was about silencing.  Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32884509/3487310) and see if it helps.

Comment: @rmaddy : +1 to that. Good old `clang -Wall -Weverything -Werror` for the Hard Mode achievement.

Answer (score -1):

Select your **target** and show **Build Phases**. Then **enter the name** of the file in the search box, and you should **see it listed** in the Compile Sources phase. **Double-click in the Compiler Flags** column for **that file** and **enter -w** to turn off all warnings for that file.