# How can I suppress the Xcode 7.3 warning "String literal is not a valid Objective-C selector"

Tags: xcode, swift

I am working on a project with some of use on Xcode 7.2 and some on 7.3 (including myself). We don't want to force everyone to upgrade to 7.3 (most would also have to update their OS and we are closing in on release date).

If I use `#selector()` as advised by Xcode for the new syntax anyone running 7.2 is unable to compile the project as they get an error. Using `Selector("…")` allows the project to compile on all versions but it creates a warning that I would love to suppress (with a TODO next to it for removal once everyone has upgraded).

Is there any way to suppress this warning, or should I just live with it for now as a price of being fast to upgrade?

**Update:** By adding `@objc` before the function in question the original warning changes to `Use '#selector' instead of explicitly constructing a 'Selector'`, and it is willing to make the change for me making the code un-compilable on Xcode 7.2 or earlier.

As the issue isn't a deprecated method neither of the two existing answers work in this case (I would use the `@avaliable` option to continue getting warnings about any other deprecated methods and make case-by-case decisions on each though).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to silence a warning in swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540446/how-to-silence-a-warning-in-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround:

```
@available(iOS, deprecated=10.0)
func _Selector(str: String) -> Selector {
    return Selector(str)
}
```

But you have to use _Selector instead of Selector in your code, And I'm not sure if Apple approves of this, so before submitting to AppStore, I Suggest remove `@available(iOS, deprecated=10.0)`.

Credit of using `@available` goes to [Daniel Thorpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197626/daniel-thorpe) for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32970249/3857417)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this working?
On your target Build settings: All
Apple LLVM Warnings - Deprecated fonctions -> NO