# How to suppress warnings in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, swift3

Using clang* I could do

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
   // ...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

However this does not work in swift.

So how to do suppress warnings in Swift?

Comment: I'm going to say warnings exist for a reason; They take notice of bad practices. Focus on fixing the warnings.

Comment: @anonman yes that's absolutely right. I'm just wondering how to do this in swift.

Comment: I totally agree with anonman. ⌘-click on the affected symbol to get the declaration. In most cases there is also a suggestion about the replacement of the deprecated API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: below instruction is for "deprecated declarations" warning. If you want to suppress different warnings then you should use flag relevant for the warning. Most of you probably use Clang, and it's warning flags can be found [here](http://www.xs-labs.com/en/blog/2012/01/10/warning-flags-clang/). So if you want to suppress for example `-Wunused-argument` you will write it with "**no**": `-Wnounused-argument`.

If you want to disable compiler warnings then go to **Project** -> **Target** -> **Build Settings** and add flag with *no* prefix to other warning flags:

[image: for all files]

If you want to disable warnings for separate file:
Go to **Project** and pick relevant **Target** -> **Build Phases** -> **Compile Sources** and flag separate file:

[image: for one file]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The warning messages are still shown. The version of my Xcode is 8.3.3.

Comment: I would like to note that the above instruction is for specific warning, which is `-Wnodeprecated-declarations`. If you want to suppress different warning you have to use different flag. Which warnings do you want to disable?

Comment: @ZhouHao can you provide a bit more information about your project? How many targets do you have? Do you use cocoapods?

Comment: Setting the Build Setting flags to disable warnings does not work for Swift projects. I have pods that are generating the `-Wincomplete-umbrella` error and having `-Wnoincomplete-umbrella` does not surpress that warnings. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540446/how-to-silence-a-warning-in-swift

Comment: @WladekSurala I have 4 targets. Yes, I use cocoapods.

Comment: I am unable to find a list of what the warning are actually called, any ideas where to find one?

I am currently getting warnings for `Overlapping Access` but i cannot find the correct flag. `-Wnooverlapping-access` does not work

Comment: @JoeMaher check out this list of warnings for clang: http://www.xs-labs.com/en/blog/2012/01/10/warning-flags-clang/ maybe you will find relevant flag for your warning, if so, post it here please:)

Comment: I've found that @WladekSurala's answer only works with Objective-C files and I also had to change the flag to -Wno-deprecated-declarations

Comment: This eliminates all warning of that type in a file, but what if you just want a single line to be excused of a certain warning?

Answer (score -1):

**This works for Xcode 10.2+ and Swift 5**

**Manual fix:**

Add `-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks` to the problematic file from Xcode > Project > Targets > Compile Sources > Double click the file where you want to turn off warnings.

**Cocoapods Fix:**

If you're trying to suppress warnings from a problematic pod, you can automatically suppress all warnings from the dependency with the `inhibit_warnings` flag in your podfile:

```
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.6', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Comment: Doesn't work for us with xcode 10.2 and swift 5. At least not in a swift file using the deprecated `INStartWorkoutIntentResponseCode.continueInApp` in SiriKit.