# Hou do I exclude any rules in swift

Tags: sonarqube

I want to exclude any rules in swift.

For example, I want to exclude "duprecated blocks".
Althouch it duprecated a little, but I want to prioritize readability.

In the case of Java, when I want to exclude warnings, I can use "@SupressWarnings" annotations.

Does swift have similar functions ?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555004/how-to-suppress-warnings-in-swift-3

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways of suppressing these issues:

- Remove the rule from the active profile - no rule, no issues. :)
- Use [exclusions to suppress the issues](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues)

Comment: Can I exclude specific issues on source code ?
Like a "NOSONAR" comment.

Comment: Via exclusions? No. For that you have the ability to mark Won't Fix or False Positive. Or... as a last resort use a //NOSONAR comment.

Comment: Thank you for comment, use to Won't Fix or False Positive.