# Ignore a warning in Swift Package manager

Tags: swift, swiftui, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have a warning from an apparent needed dependency when trying to install the [Amplify Swift Package](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios):

```
Showing Recent Messages
ignoring declared target(s) 'swift-nio-zlib-support' in the system package
```

How can I ignore that warning? I tried [this suggested](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127377) solution but didn't clear it. I just want to suppress that one specifically without affecting any other.

Pd: I don't have any pods, I'm using swift package manager.

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible with Swift Compiler because it doesn't support specific flags to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540446/how-to-silence-a-warning-in-swift